# SQLite bug in WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sqlite, debugging

Can anyone confirm that this is a bug?

```
CREATE TABLE meta 
 meta_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
 localAbsPathAndName TEXT, 
 purgeGUID TEXT 
);

INSERT INTO meta (localAbsPathAndName) VALUES ('C:\some\path');
INSERT INTO meta (localAbsPathAndName) VALUES ('C:\some\path');

SELECT * FROM  meta WHERE purgeGUID!='aa5de571c9da5e3995b63427f5d23aad'
```

incorrectly returns no rows.

Comment: just download "SQLite Browser" and make the table and test it.. I assure you it take 30 seconds

Answer (score 3):

purgeGUID is null so Sqlite works correctly because

`null != 'aa5de571c9da5e3995b63427f5d23aad'` is null

Condition "where null' is never fulfilled

Comment: "null" is not equal to 'aa5de571c9da5e3995b63427f5d23aad' so it should be true, this is definitely the cause (I agree) but it is a bug in sqlite nullexception misreport inside the engine I suspect, you an try this is any other type of SQL (say, MysQL or MS SQL) you can see that I am right

Comment: @MrHeelis, you misunderstand null in SQL. Read [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/), for example.

Comment: "null != 'aa5de571c9da5e3995b63427f5d23aad' is false" it is actually `null`, not `false`

Comment: @ixSci - good point, answer updated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 columns in your 'meta' table but you provide only one value in insert query.Provide the 3 values and try again it works

Comment: SQLite has an implicit DEFAULTVALUE(NULL) if no other default is specified.